# how arrayDeque.peek() Method in java working with while loop

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.ArrayDeque;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayDeque<Integer> arrayDeque = new ArrayDeque<>();
        arrayDeque.push(10);
        arrayDeque.push(11);
        arrayDeque.push(15);
        arrayDeque.push(20);
        arrayDeque.push(200);
        arrayDeque.add(700);
        while (arrayDeque.peek() != null) {
            System.out.println(arrayDeque.pop() + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Good Day .. I have a question regarding the peek() method in ArrayDeque Class .. all the method will do is retrieve the head of the arrayDeque without removing it. so if that is the case how it's working perfectly without going for an infinite loop .. I mean who told the Method to look for the Next element after each complete loop.

Comment: What does `pop()` do?

Comment: Your `while` loop is calling the `pop()` method for your `ArrayDeque` object.  Look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html#pop() to get a better understanding of what exactly this is doing.

Comment: public E removeFirst() {
        E x = pollFirst();
        if (x == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return x;
    }

Comment: @WaseemSwaileh - yes. `pop()` would be equivalent to `removeFirst()`. Did you read the Javadoc to see what `pop()` actually does? Does your `ArrayDeque` **change** whenever `pop()` is called?

Comment: yes thanks dear .. I got it now .. Stupid ques

Comment: @WaseemSwaileh - Not a stupid question.  We're just pointing you in the right direction so you can answer the question yourself :)

Comment: Really Thanks .. I just begun lately learning java .. and there is a lot of load on my head .. sometimes I ask such questions ..

Comment: @WaseemSwaileh - I've totally been there.  It just takes practice.  Keep coding and keep reading other people's code.  That's the best way to become good at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no infinite loop because the condition in the whole loop will be false when the queue is empty.

```
while (arrayDeque.peek() != null)
```

When `pop` removes the last element, `arrayDeque.peek()` will return null and that's the end.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably why I prefer to check for `isEmpty()`.
This makes it easier to grasp that you need to pop elements off the queue or it will never go emtpy.

```
 while (!arrayDeque.isEmpty()) { arrayDeque.pop(); }
```